# How do media timeline apps work under the hood?

Tags: audio, media, midi

There are numerous examples of apps that are time-based and send out events or carry out complex processing to a very fine resolution and accuracy. Think MIDI sequencing apps, audio and video editing apps.

So I'm curious, at their core level, how do these apps do what they do so accurately from a programming point of view?

Answer (score 0):

MIDI and media playback are entirely different in nature, and are handled in different ways.

For MIDI, there is very little data to process.  A thread with a high priority is created to handle MIDI I/O.  That's all that is needed.

For audio, accuracy isn't a problem but latency is.  There is a buffer on the sound interface that is regularly written to by the software playing back audio.  For a typical media player, this buffer has storage for about 300ms of audio.  The software just writes the PCM-encoded audio waveform to the buffer.  The sound interface is constantly reading from this buffer and playing back at a constant rate.

For low-latency audio applications, this buffer size can be very small, handling as little as 5 or 10ms of audio.  The software generating the audio data must again be handled by a thread with high priority, and often has many optimizations that keep it running in the event the rest of the software (effects and what not) cannot keep up.  Buffer underruns are common.  Special drivers are often used to skip unneeded software in the signal chain.  ASIO and DirectX are common on Windows.  Windows Vista/7 and OSX both call their audio APIs "core audio", and provide low-latency features without special drivers.

Video is an entirely different beast.  Decoding the video is handled by hardware, where possible.  This is how a slow device such as a cell phone is able to playback 720p video.  If the hardware can handle the codec, the software just needs to send it the data.  In cases where the codec is unsupported, the video must be decoded in software which is much slower.  Even on modern PCs, software decoding often leads to choppy or laggy video.

Synchronization of audio to video is also a problem.  I don't know much about it, but it is my understanding that the audio is the master clock, and video is synchronized to it.  You cannot simply start playback and expect the timing to work out, as different sound interfaces will have different ideas as to what 44.1kHz (or any other sample rate) is.  You can prove this yourself by playing back the same audio on two different devices simultaneously, and listening to them drift apart over time.

Comment: Thanks Brad. Let me be more specific about what I'm looking for.

Comment: Let's take latency out of the equation and say I want to play a video file and synchronise some audio gain events to it.

So at 5.010 seconds I want the gain to be 100%, and at 7.850 seconds I want the gain to be 75% with a linear change between the keyframes. 

How does that work?

Comment: @martinjbaker, Your time in seconds corresponds to a specific sample offset in the audio stream.  Those samples are manipulated.